# Custom Ransacker to ignore dash in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ransack

I'm trying to customize Ransack to allow searching the text field and possibly having ransack ignore the `dash` character.

#### EXAMPLE:

If I type this in the search box:

```
123456
```

The Ransack query will not find this record in the DB:

```
123-456
```

Right now if I don't type the dash the record will not be found. I understand why it's trying to match the DB record and it's obviously not finding it because the dash is required to find that record.

Is it possible to customize Ransack so that the search will still find the record without the dash in the params?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like creating a custom Ransacker does the trick here.

```
ransacker :number do
  Arel.sql("translate(number, '-', '')")
end
```

This will remove the dashes from the database representation of the data when searching with Ransack.